# Embed Analytics Dashboard with Filter Logged In User

Tags: lightning, einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, analytics-bindings

I want to [embed a Lightning Analytics Dashboard and apply a filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_embed_lightning.htm&type=5) to display a filtered set of records from my dataset in a dashboard. In this situation `Case` records, where filtered where *Case's owner is the currently logged in user*, so `Case.OwnerId == CurrentUserId`

```
{
    "datasets": {
        "Case_Dataset": [
            {
                "fields": [
                    "Case_Owner.Id"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "operator": "matches",
                    "values": [
                        "$CurrentUser.Id" // ???
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can't figure out the merge-syntax for `Logged In User's Id` (Like `UserInfo` static class in Visualforce...)

I see there are fields for ***record context***, like `$Name`, or `$Id`...

**UPDATE**

Trying to attack the problem at the `SOQL`/`SAQL` level, I have tried to create a new dashboard, and instead, add the `filter` to the `SAQL` like so:

```
q = load "Case_Dataset";
q = filter q by 'Case_Owner.Id' matches "\'!{User.Id}\'";
```

Which works, when I run the query it doesn't throw an error at least.

When editing the overall JSON for the dashboard (pressing, cmd-e) I see:

```
lens_1": {
         "type": "saql",
         "query": "q = load \"Case_Dataset\";\nq = filter q by 'Case_Owner.Id' matches \"\\'0051N0000075pHRQAY\\'\"; ...",
...
```

In the `query` field of my step, looks like the string-value of my user-id has been merged! But why would it display *my user id* if I am using a merge-field? Will it get reflected when the dashboard is rendered by another user?

Interestingly enough, if I close the dashboard without saving and reload it I see the following (in the query field of the step?!)

```
\nq = filter q by 'Case_Owner.Id' matches \"\\'!{User.Id}\\'\"
```

This was inspired by [this post](http://www.salesforceblogger.com/2017/06/27/how-to-filter-dashboard-by-logged-in-user/) - so I am going to try to change the step type to SOQL.

**UPDATE**

Working with Salesforceforceblogger's [great series on "bindings"](http://www.salesforceblogger.com/all-about-bindings/) has provided a lot of insight into how I should be going about this - so going forward I'm digging in deeper with that and will post results here once I figure it out. Also found [documentation on bindings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_bindings.meta/bi_dev_guide_bindings/bi_dbjson_bindings.htm)

**RESULTS**

I will leave this question open, as I would like anyone to post more concrete examples (especially since "global dashboard filters", as I could not get that working).

I ultimately create a [SOQL query step](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_steps_types_soql.htm), that used the `!{User.Id}` merge field to select the logged in user's ID, and filtered my `Case` records where `OwnerId` field matched.

Example (from dashboard editor, `cmd-e`, edit JSON to insert):

```
"logged_in_user": {
  "groups": [],
  "numbers": [],
  "query": "select id from User where id = '!{User.Id}'",
  "selectMode": "single",
  "strings": [
    "Id"
  ],
  "type": "soql"
},
```

I then used [binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_steps_types_soql.htm) in the various step's SAQL queries to filter the results for each query like so:

```
\nq = filter q by {{column(logged_in_user.result, [\"Id\"]).asEquality(\"OwnerId\")}};
```

***Note: It's possible to add this query in the SAQL editor (but you should not add the `\n` or `\` escape characters around the quotation marks.***

So just adding the following line in the SAQL editor works as well.

```
q = filter q by {{column(logged_in_user.result,["Id"]).asEquality("OwnerId")}};
```

**On the global filters:**

Despite trying a TON of different combinations with the [global dashboard filter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_filters_parameters.htm), none would work correctly, for example:

```
"filters": [
            "label":"Current User",
            "fields": [
                "OwnerId"
            ],
            "dataset": "PLsvc_Case_Dataset",
            "operator": "matches",
            "locked":true,
            "value": "{{column(logged_in_user.result, [\"Id\"]).asObject()}}"

        ],
```

I also tried with `cell()` and `asString()` bindings, wrapping the `"value":[...]` as an array, etc. etc. And none of it worked the same!

**Compact Filter Syntax:**

```
"query": {
   ...
   "filters": [
       "OwnerId",
       [ 
          "{{column(logged_in_user.result, [\"Id\"]).asObject()}}"
       ],
       "in"  
   ]
}
```

**Note:** *Compact filter syntax is different the SAQL, and depending on how you add the widget, or if you access the "SAQL Editor" for the step in the tool, the compact filters are converted to SAQL in the overall JSON editor for the dashboard!?!*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ***Finally cracked this!***

The above wasn't quite clear, although it did help somewhat so kudos anyway. But in an attempt to demystify things I've put the below together:

---

Step 1:
Go to your CRMA dashboard and press (CTRL + E/CMD + E for Mac) - this should open the query JSON

---

Step 2:
Under the steps key in the JSON, paste the following

```
"QueryLoginUser_1": {
            "broadcastFacet": true,
            "groups": [],
            "numbers": [],
            "query": "SELECT Id, Name FROM User Where Id = '!{User.Id}'",
            "receiveFacetSource": {
                "mode": "all",
                "steps": []
            },
            "selectMode": "single",
            "strings": [],
            "type": "soql",
            "useGlobal": true
        },
```

It should look like this
[image]

This should create a new Query source:
[image]

---

Step 3:
Now, double click on any of the dashboard widgets which should bring up this menu to the right

[image]

Now click on Query, and then click on Advanced Editor

This will now show this:

[image]

In Source Query select "QueryLoginUser_1" that we just created
[image]

In Source Data select the following
[image]

This is going to give you the following interaction, please copy this
[image]

---

Step 4:
As per the [documentation][8] we now have to create a filter, so

Go back to your dashboard and same as step 1 press CTRL + E again. Find the "sources" key and paste the interaction query we just copied in a filter in the "filters" sub key.

[image]

```
[
                                "Household.OwnerId",
                                [
                                    "{{cell(QueryLoginUser_1.result, 0, \"Id\").asString()}}"
                                ],
                                "in"
                            ]
```

Obviously "Household.OwnerId" will be different in your case.

---

Answer (score 1):

I combined the information form here: [How to filter dashboard by logged-in user](https://www.salesforceblogger.com/2017/06/27/how-to-filter-dashboard-by-logged-in-user/)

and here: [SAQL String Filter Bindings With Commenting](http://www.sfdcr.com/analytics/saql-string-filter-bindings-commenting/)

so I added this to the JSON:

```
"UserData":{
   "groups":[],
   "numbers":[],
   "query":"SELECT Name, Country, Id FROM User WHERE Id = '!{User.Id}'",
   "selectMode":"single",
   "strings":[
      "Name",
      "Country",
      "Id"
   ],
   "type":"soql"
}
```

Then I find the data field in my query that matched the data with the userID.  I followed the SFDCer post to create a static step and then filter my query to only show currently logged in user data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a security predicate to filter the dataset for the dashboard (on the Lightning app Home page) to records where the owner was the running user, worked great!
'AccountOwner.LastName' == "$User.LastName"